# FileNotFoundException error when using a runnable Jar File in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, filenotfoundexception

I am working on an assignment that involves the use of 2 txt files and creating a runnable jar file. Part of the assignment involves creating a runnable jar file called Hw2.jar, exporting that file into the "first directory level", then going into run configurations in the arguments tab and pasting, "java -jar hw2.jar ct.search ct.corpus" (the ct.search and ct.corpus files are the txt files) Here is what it looks like.

[image: This is what my project files look like, with the hw2.jar file in the directory]

[image: And here is what the run configurations look like]

Yet despite having completed the steps, I'm getting a FileNotFoundException Error, as detailed below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: -jar (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source)     at
>   edu.iastate.cs228.hw2.Console.main(Console.java:29)

This is my first time trying to use a runnable jar file within the run configurations, so I am unfamiliar with how exactly the process works. I would very much appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you.

EDIT: The jar and txt files are NOT in the src folder. They are inside of the project folder.

Comment: Exporting it as a runnable JAR does not include files outside the source folder and files inside a JAR cannot be accessed in Java as `java.io.File`. Search for `jar` and `getResourceAsStream` to find out how to adapt your code to make it work also when packed as a JAR.

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and can't be accessed using file APIs such as FileInputStream. Use getResourceAsStream.

Answer (score 0):

From your first screenshot, it looks like all of the corpus files and the jar are inside the `src` folder (you can confirm if this is the case if you collapse the `src` folder by clicking on the triangle icon). Use cut and paste them at the project level.

Comment: I can confirm the files are not within the src folder. They are in the project folder